# Mock window object for ES2020 module, Angular server build

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, referenceerror

I mock window object using global variable like this `global["window"]={location:{}};`

It works in CommonJS module type. but not when using module type es2020. but I have specific need for es2020.

I went through multiple documentation to figure it out. But no luck. I am getting window reference error.

A solution to mock window object in Angular SSR build with es2020 module type.

Comment: It doesn't work in what way?